# How to read a single character with Google OCR vision-samples

Tags: android-vision

Is there any way to recognize single character in android OCR vision-samples?

I know it is a known issue, the OCR works well with lines but not with single character or numbers.

I'm wondering if it could be possible in a scenario where there is a single character, which is one of these three:

- 1
- 2
- X

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to improve the formatting. Please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question and post the code you have tried if any. Good luck!